# Backbone function implementation with Event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new backbone so need some quick help. I've tried out different things but each result into syntax error.

```
var extremeModel =  new AlertLevel.Type(this.model.get('extreme').attributes);          

if ( !this.validateAlertLevel(extremeModel, 
    {
        'smsEnable' : this.$el.find('.smsEnable').is(':checked') extremeModel.get("smsEnable"); //ERROR: Re-write it to if/else
    })
)
return;
```

How can I write below statement in one line.

```
this.$el.find('.smsEnable').is(':checked') extremeModel.get("smsEnable");
```

if its checked

```
this.$el.find('.smsEnable').is(':checked')
```

than do this;

```
extremeModel.get("smsEnable");
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="smsEnable" checked>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'smsEnable' : (this.$el.find('.smsEnable').is(':checked')? extremeModel.get("smsEnable"):'' /* or whatever result if false */)
```